# How to log to console in c#

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, console, console-application

I want to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging in order to log stuff to the console. I have set it up like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());
    ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
    logger.LogInformation("Current directory {0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
}
```

However, nothing is written to the console.

Comment: You do not need to dispose if you are sending more data to logger.  You need to flush().  You are writing to a stream and windows will not continuously write the stream to the file.  Windows uses timers and size to move the data from a stream to a file.   The flush will move the data from the stream to a file.

Comment: Maybe flushing stdout would also fix the problem, however according to this issue https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/631 disposing of /something/ is the correct way to go.

Comment: You only dispose when you end the application, not in the middle. Yes dispose will fix issue when application terminates nicely, but not when application crashes.  When you crash you still want to see the logger data and if you didn't dispose you are lost.

Comment: That is the point of the `using` keyword, to make sure the object is also disposed of in case of an exception. Edit: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement "The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs within the using block."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the `ConsoleLoggerProvider`, which is added to the `loggerFactory` by `AddConsole`, is `IDisposable` and must be disposed of, in order to flush the output. Disposing of the `loggerFactory` will accomplish that. So either call `loggerFactory.Dispose()` at the end of the program or add `using` when creating the loggerFactory like so:

```
static void Main()
{
    using ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());
    ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
    logger.LogInformation("Current directory {0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
}
```

Comment: Just posted this Q&A because it took me way too long to find out how to do this without resorting to heavy machinery like `ServiceCollection` or ASP.NET Generic Host.

Comment: That's correct but also remember to add the Nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console otherwise .AddConsole cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this (without using the GenericHost) is using the `ServiceCollection` standalone.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var collection = new ServiceCollection();
    collection.AddLogging(b => {
        b.AddConsole();
        b.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
    });
    var sp = collection.BuildServiceProvider();

    using(var scope = sp.CreateScope())
    {
        var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogInformation("Current directory {0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    }
}
```

[.netfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O7Myl4)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had seen this solution earlier, but I felt it was too much boilerpolate just to get logging to work properly. I strongly think that each package/module should work on its own without the need to have three other classes and objects around. As I commented below my own answer, I was specifically looking for a way to get logging working without adding stuff that I don't need for anything else. Maybe that shouldn't have been a comment but part of the question.

Comment: @Sunday yes fine I just wanted to add this here for completeness if somebody needs logging and is ok with ```ServiceCollection```. But yes you are also right and thats also my opinion. Nevertheless this is the way it works in net-core :)

Comment: Thanks again, obviously you are right that this answer will also be useful for many who (are willing to) use `ServiceCollection` and fits perfectly the question as stated. Let's wait and see which question get's more upvotes if any ;)